# Canceling HTTP response in interceptor not working / memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

- I make HTTP requests using Axios and my own wrapper code.
- All responses are intercepted and printed to the console.
- All responses include a '*data.status*' property that I use as a simple check to see if everything worked.

---

## Problem

**Step 1: Access /Home**

[image]

- Only one HTTP request is made to check permissions. The response is printed to the console.

**Step 2: Access /Staff**

[image]

- Initial check for permissions passes and response is printed.
- A second HTTP request is made to get info from the database. This is purposefully set to fail.
- data.status == false, the response is still printed but the cancel code is activated.

**Step 3: Access /Home**

[image]

- For some reason, two responses are printed to the console. There should only be one!

---

## Code

- **Interceptor** (https://pastebin.com/g6uGwBj1)

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if(!response.data.status){
          throw new axios.Cancel(response.data.message);
        }
        return response;
    },
    function(error) {
        cancel();
        window.Event.fire('addError', "Error "+error.message);
        return Promise.reject(error);
   }
);
```

- **Post** (https://pastebin.com/dFtFcfnK)

```
post(url, data, successCb = null) {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: domain+url,
      data: data,
      cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) { cancel = c; })
    })
    .then(successCb)
    .catch(function(err){
      if(axios.isCancel(err)){ console.log('im canceled'); }
      else{ console.log('im server response error'); }
    });
}
```

Comment: A response of 200 with data.status=false is not a failed response. A failed response would be 500 or 400 responses. Or maybe requesting json with jQuery and returning html (request network is fine but response can't be JSON parsed). Maybe in your contract with the API status=false means failure but as far as axios is concerned the network request returned parsable data. Try returning the response with a appropriate 400 status code.

Comment: Because of my silly code, all responses have status 200 - so they all enter the response function. Inside of that I then check data.status, if it is false I manually throw an error myself.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can call cancel when the response already came in. Can you not just return 'Promise.reject("no positive data status")'

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks for the suggestion.